# Error al descargar imágenes de api en Python

Tags: python

Tengo un código simple. Lo que quiero es descargar las imágenes de la API, pero no las descarga.

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.habbo.es/extradata/public/users/hhes-aafb213bbe8a70df33faa0259cfb5f33/photos"
data = requests.get(url).json()
for key in data:
    response = requests.get(data[0]['url'])
    filename = data[0]['url'].split("/")[-1]
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

¿Cómo podría descargar todas las imágenes a una carpeta?

Tengo el siguiente error:
[image: Error python]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

La url de la imagen en la API es incorrecta por lo que hay que modificarla. Yo lo hice de la siguiente forma

```
import requests

url = "https://www.habbo.es/extradata/public/users/hhes-aafb213bbe8a70df33faa0259cfb5f33/photos"
data = requests.get(url).json()
for key in data:

#borramos las // y agregamos  https://

    response = requests.get(data[0]['url'].replace('//','https://',1))



        
    filename = data[0]['url'].split("/")[-1]
    
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

Espero haberte ayudado.